# Interval in which $x=2t^3-3t^2$ is negative

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

> A particle move along x-axis so that its position is given by $x=2t^3-3t^2$ at time $t$ sec. What is the time interval during which the particle will be on the negative half of the axis ?

$$
x=2t^3-3t^2=t^2(2t-3)<0\implies\boxed{t<\dfrac{3}{2}}\\
\frac{dx}{dt}=6t^2-6t=6t(t-1)=0\implies t=0\text{ or } t=1\\
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=12t-6\\
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\Big|_{t=0}=-6<0\;;\quad\;\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\Big|_{t=1}=6>0\\
x(t=0)=0\;;\quad\;x(t=1)=-1\\
x(t=3/2)=0
$$

My reference gives the solution $0<t<3/2$, so where does the lower limit $0$ comes from ?

Comment: No need to differentiate.

Comment: Time starts at zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$t$ is time, hence $t \ge 0.$ Furthermore we have $x(0)=0.$

Hence:

the particle will be on the negative half of the axis $ \iff 0<t<3/2.$

Comment: why the downvote ???

Comment: I did not downvote, but why are you considering that time $t$ is necessarily positive?

Answer (score 0):

Hint (for avoiding differentiation) :
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{sgn}(2t^3-3t^2) &= \mathrm{sgn}(t^2(2t-3))\\
&= \mathrm{sgn}(2t-3)\\
&= \mathrm{sgn}\left(t-\frac 32\right)
\end{align*}